How to properly replace NSTextView's string when used with bindings
I have issues with string replacement when there are newlines.
How to properly replace string or part of a string so that bindings are triggered.
I have used open func replaceCharacters(in range: NSRange, with string: String) but it doesn't trigger bindings.
When I use func insertText(_ string: Any, replacementRange: NSRange) I have to do the NSString dancing
let textView = NSTextView()
textView.string = "LongString with newlines\r\nGuten Tag!"
textView.string.count //prints 35
(textView.string as NSString).length //prints 36
textView.insertText("XX", replacementRange: NSMakeRange(0, (textView.string as NSString).length)

I feel I am fighting the framework. What is the correct (swift) way?
Mind that textView.string = "XX" doesn't trigger bindings

Trigger the binding in the opposite direction. Change the data in a KVO way and the text view will follow.

Just tested. While it works with bindings it will mess the selectedRange in the NSTextView (move cursor to the end). My example looks like I intend to replace. Sorry for the confussion.

How about the Continuously Updates Value binding option?

To trigger binding the preferable way is to use insertText(_ string: Any, replacementRange: NSRange)
textView.insertText("", replacementRange: NSRange(..<someIndex, in: text))

It's also possible to use  replaceCharacters(in range: NSRange, with string: String) followed by didChangeText() directly on the NSTextView.
textView.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(..<someIndex, in: text), with: "")
textView.didChangeText()

NOTE: Do not modify text in delegate calls such as textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) . This causes undo coalescing and upon undoing your app will crash.
